# Yii 2 static pages

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager, viewaction

I can't show static pages. Try do it as described in doc here - http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2-guide.pdf (on page 100) but when I enable prettyurl, it doesn't work.

Added in urlManager rules:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '' => 'site/index',
        'login' => 'site/login',
        'contacts' => 'site/contact',
        '<view:(break)>'=>'/site/page?&view=<view>',
    ),
),
```

then in SiteController added:

```
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            ...
            'page' => [
                'class'=>'yii\web\ViewAction',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

And then created views/site/pages/break.php

```
<h1>View static page Break</h1>
```

But I get an error:
*Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request: site/page?&view=break*

If i disable prettyUrl:

```
//'enablePrettyUrl'=>true
```

then i can see my page typing url: index.php?r=site/page&view=break

What's wrong with ViewAction?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing the rules part of your url manage wrong.
Try this

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    ],
```

The rules part should be important..

Comment: yes, now 'site/page?&view=break' opens the page break.php, but how to make more seo-friendly url? like just 'site.ru/break'

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. use such lines:

```
'<view:(break)>' => 'site/page',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

I force use specific name of page for view, in my case it "break", because can't use this

```
'<view:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>' => 'site/page',
```

(it causes crashing other rules.) I think it could better create "own rule class" extending UrlRule, but think that now I don't need this.

Comment: `'<view:(break)>' => 'site/page'`
This is the way to go !

Comment: Note that this rule should work as well :  
`'<view:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>' => 'site/page'`  
It should be declared last though, otherwise it will catch all other patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried this way (without rules specification) :

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => 'false'
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple:

1. web.php code is like this `'rules' => [

               'site/page/<view:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>' => 'site/index',`
2. In SiteController don't use function actions(), instead:

`public function actionIndex ($view)
    {
        return $this->render('/site/pages/' . $view);
    } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
    throw new HttpException(404);
  }`.

3. If view contacts.php exists in views/site/pages/ , url is yourdomain/basic/web/site/page/contact

4.Thanks to samdark and it's article https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2932